# why a^m b^n where m,n > 0 is a regular language but a^n b^n where n > 0 is non regular language

Tags: regex, regular-language, computation-theory, finite-automata

a^m b^n where m,n >= 0 is a regular language but why a^n b^n where n >= 0 is a non-regular language?
In both languages, we are taking an infinite number of a's and b's but why we could build a Finite Automata for the first case and not for the second case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider the above languages as A,B:

```
X = a^m b^n where m,n>0 
Y = a^n b^n where n>0
```

Language **X** is a regular language but Language **Y** is not a regular language because we cannot construct a Finite automata for language **Y**.

A language is  not a regular language if the language does not satisfy the pumping lemma , but if the language satisfies the pumping lemma  then the language need not be regular.

In case of language **X** the number of a's and b's are different so we need not remember number of occurrences of 'a' after accepting all a's we can accept b's and move to final state ,but in case of language **Y** the number of a's and b's are same. So all the strings in the language **Y** should contain equal number of a's and equal number of b's. So we need to remember the number of a's  so that b's can be evaluated, which is not possible using finite automata.
So to evaluate tese kind of languages push down automata is required.

```
PushDown automata = Finite automata + some amount of memory(stack).
```

The languages of the kind **Y** are called context free language and they can be evaluated using Pushdown Automata(PDA).Finite automata do not have any memory to store the count of a's and b's. where as pushdown automata has some amount of memory so we can evaluate languages of type **Y**.

For this language **Y** we need to push all the a's on to the stack and whenever we encounter b's then we need to pop a's(remembering the condition that all the a's must be before b's).If all the a's are not before b's  then we need to move the system to dead state.

Answer (score 0):

In the second language the number of a's and b's have to be the same.
The finite automata would need the ability to count the number of a's to check if the number of b's are the same. This would need an infinite amount of states.

Maybe check out the pumping lemma on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages

Answer (score 0):

```
By using pumping lemma we have to proove the above language is not a regular language
L=a^nb^n
n->is the no.of states
We have to solve this problem by using two methods
1.one way is to simply considering an example
2.another way is to by simply substituting the i values in uv^iw
First we have to take Z=a^nb^n
And then Z=uv^iw
v is a substring
For example n=1
•Z=ab
n=2
•Z=aabb
n=3
•Z=aaabbb
The selection of v comes under 3 cases
For example
Case1:
v is a substring only a`s
 For example assume v=a^x
x is the no.of repetitions
•Z is written in uv^iw
If i=0
Z=a^n-x.1.b^n does not belongs to L
Case2:
Consider only b`s
Assume v=b^x
For i=0
Z=a^nb^n-x does not belongs to L
Case3:
Consider only a`sb`s
Assume v=a^xb^x
For i=0
Z=a^n-xb^n-x€L
For i=1
Z=a^n-xa^xb^xb^n-x
 =a^nb^n€L
For i=2
Z=a^n-x(a^xb^x)^2b^n-x
 =a^n-xa^xb^xa^xb^xb^n-x doesn't belongs to L
 The string start with always a`s followed by b`s
We are getting one more additional ab (or) ba but our string of Length n.
So above the three conditions are not satisfiying so...The given Language is not a regular language



In the first case..a^mb^n m and n are not equal m may be Greater than n or less than n or may be equal to n ...so..it is a regular language...
```

Comment: Please note the conventions for formatting [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).